# Way To Speed Up Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, optimization, cte

My query returns roughly 590 rows and 8 columns.  The issue that I have is that from start to finish the query takes 2 minutes 30 seconds to complete.  The great group of people on here have taught me a lot on how to write more efficient queries, so here is another!

I am using a `date` variable  and not a `datetime` since my variable only contains a date - and I am also using storing my date(s) in the `yyyymmdd` format as suggested by [Aaron Bertrand - Bad Habits To Kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries).

Is there anything I can do to optimize this query and have the results return faster?

```
DECLARE @Startdate date = '20170101', 
        @Enddate   date = '20170131';

WITH fc As
(
    Select
    Teacher
    ,Team
    ,fc
    FROM [Helper].[dbo].[fc]
)
,ia As
(
    Select
    Teacher
    ,tia
    FROM dbo.ia
    WHERE [hiredate] >= @Startdate
    AND [hiredate] <  DATEADD(DAY,1,@Enddate)
)
,inb As
(
    Select 
    Teacher
    ,tinb
    FROM inb
),
ripcord As
(
    Select
    Teacher
    ,pit
    FROM [homebase].[dbo].[rip]
)
,YRTR As
(
    Select
    Teacher
    ,totamt
    FROM totamt
    WHERE CAST([begindate] As DATE) BETWEEN CAST(DateAdd(yy, -1, @startdate) As Date) 
                                     AND CAST(DateAdd(yy, -1, @enddate) As Date)
)
Select 
DISTINCT rost.[Teacher] As Teacher
,[Team Name] = fc.team
,[TIA] = ROUND(SUM(ISNULL(ia.tia,0)),0)
,[SUM] = CAST(ROUND(SUM(ISNULL(inb.tinb,0))+SUM(ISNULL(rip.pit,0)),0) As INT)
,[YR] = ROUND(SUM(ISNULL(tr.totamt,0)),0)
,[fc] = ISNULL(fc,0)
,[1st Count] = COALESCE(b.[students],0)
,[2nd Count] = COALESCE(c.[potstudents],0)
FROM dbo.roster rost
LEFT JOIN fc fc
ON rost.Teacher = fc.Teacher
LEFT JOIN ia ia
ON ia.Teacher = rost.Teacher
LEFT JOIN inb inb
ON rost.Teacher = inb.Teacher
LEFT JOIN ripcord rip
ON rost.Teacher = rip.Teacher
LEFT JOIN YRTR tr
ON rost.Teacher = tr.Teacher
OUTER APPLY
( SELECT 
        DISTINCT Teacher [Teacher]
        , COUNT(students) AS students
    FROM students
    WHERE Teacher = rost.Teacher
    AND regdate >= @Startdate
    AND regdate <  DATEADD(DAY,1,@Enddate)
    GROUP BY Teacher
) AS b
OUTER APPLY
(
    Select
    DISTINCT Teacher Teacher
    ,COUNT(potstudents) As potstudents
    FROM dbo.potstudents
    WHERE Teacher = rost.Teacher
    AND returndate >= @Startdate
    AND returndate <  DATEADD(DAY,1,@Enddate)
    GROUP BY Teacher
) AS c
GROUP BY rost.[Teacher],fc.TEAM, fc.fc,b.[students],c.[potstudents]
ORDER BY rost.[Teacher] ASC
```

**EDIT** 
(forgot the link, sorry)
At the requet of @sabin bio - here is a link to the [Query Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1SQmgRdg)

Also, the CTE's query views which have no indexes on them.

Comment: What about indexes ? do you have ? ( something on `teacher` , `regdate` , and what about `begindate`  it is datetime type? maybe cast other way around  )  also can you post the execution plan ? (here is a way : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ )

Comment: You are using `Distinct` in both `Outer Apply` even you have `Group By` - try to add also the `Teacher ID`  and you will not need `distinct`

Comment: Please post your table schema, index design and query plan.

Comment: The `yyyymmdd` string format is for date literals in T-SQL. When you store date values in a native `date` data type, the actual value is stored in a 4-byte binary structure.

Comment: @sabinbio - the CTE's are querying views and they have no indexes.

Comment: @SqlZim, yes that should be 3 bytes. Too bad I can't edit the comment to fix it.

Comment: @sabinbio - Just added a link to the pastetheplan that shows query & Execution plan.

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh try do add indexes to your underlying tables. Your's tables seems to be heaps (with no clustered index) - and depending on your work , this could be good or not. Indexes on join fields would help.

Comment: @sabinbio - unfortunately I am not able to edit the underlying ntables to add/alter indexes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by understanding the plan that the query optimizer generated by your query. In your question you say that the query returns around 590 rows but the query plan included only returns 18 rows. Did you attach the correct plan? I will walk through it anyway. Reading from right to left:

Do a full table scan of `roster` and get back 18 rows. This result set is used as the outer part of all of the following nested loop joins. For each row in the outer result set:

- Do a full scan on the `ia` table
- Do a full scan on the `inb` table
- Do a full scan on the `ripcord` table
- Do a full scan on the `YRTR` table
- Do a full scan on the `students` table
- Do a full scan on the `potstudents` table

At some point the number of rows gets bumped up to 19. The `GROUP BY` is implemented as the `SORT` with a node id of 4. The `DISTINCT` is implemented as a `Sort (Distinct Sort)` with a node id of 0.

As the programmer you do not have direct control over the query plan but there's a lot that you can do to influence it. You said that the query execution time is too slow. Does the above plan sound efficient to you? Is it what you would do if you could choose the query optimizer's actions? You're doing around 140 table scans just to return 18 rows. For a very small number of rows this might be okay but it sounds like you have more data in production.

One way to optimize a query is to reduce the IO requirements of that query. Here you are doing lots of table scans so that should be straightforward to implement. Create indexes so that the query optimizer can get the relevant data more efficiently. Even if you are referencing views you can create indexes on the tables used by the view to improve performance. To give you an example, here is the predicate for the table access on `fc`:

```
[Test].[dbo].[roster].[Teacher] as [rost].[Teacher]=[Test].[dbo].[fc].[Teacher]
```

If you create an index on the `Teacher` column of `fc` that may result in a different, and possibly more efficient, table access method for that table. Optionally, you could add all of the columns used by the Teacher table as `INCLUDE` columns.

Looking at just your code, you should be aware of the impact of using local variables in your query. The query optimizer will not know the values of those local variables when creating a query plan. It will do default cardinality estimates based on hard-coded rules. For some queries, adding an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint or replacing the local variables with hard-coded values can result in a much better query plan because the query optimizer knows the values of the variables before creating the plan.

Also, do not haphazardly add `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` to your queries. It looks like the query optimizer optimized away some of them, but most of the time if you have both `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` in the same query you're doing something wrong. It is not clear how much of a performance impact making that change would have for this query.

Answer (score 1):

Please stop using `distinct` unnecessarily.  Not just the outer apply subqueries, but the main query itself.

Another thing you can try: remove the outer apply subqueries.  Add the tables and match conditions as `left joins` instead.  In the main query, change to `count(distinct student pk)`.

There are a few other things you can try, but I'd focus on those outer applies, or at least look at the execution plan, and figure out where to focus.

Another important thing to check is that you have the proper indexes on the tables.  Considering how few results you have, there may be missing indexes.

I noticed a lot of table scans in your plan.  Consider adding indexes to the columns you are joining on frequently, but also on these dates if you are commonly filtering them.

You should alter the underlying tables.  You can create indexed views, but that has a lot of restrictions and is not a substitute for indexing tables. Putting indexes on views can be a good way to move performance strain from `select`s (reading) data, to `insert`s, `update`s, and `delete`s (writing) data at the cost of disk space.  It has amazing performance benefits, but not without a cost.

[Joe Obbish's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/164108) has a more complete response to your query plan.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `CTE` where you are doing a `select` with no `where`
Just use the the table directly

```
Select [rost].[Teacher] As Teacher
     , [Team Name] = fc.team 
     , [fc] = ISNULL(fc, 0) 

     , [1st Count] = count(b.[students])
     , [2nd Count] = count(c.potstudents)
     , [TIA] = ROUND(SUM(ISNULL(ia.tia, 0)), 0)
     , [SUM] = CAST(ROUND(SUM(ISNULL(inb.tinb, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(rip.pit, 0)), 0) As INT)
     , [YR]  = ROUND(SUM(ISNULL(tr.totamt, 0)), 0)    
FROM dbo.roster rost
LEFT JOIN fc 
       ON fc.Teacher  = rost.Teacher 
LEFT JOIN ia
       ON ia.Teacher  = rost.Teacher
LEFT JOIN inb inb
       ON inb.Teacher = rost.Teacher
LEFT JOIN ripcord rip
      ON  rip.Teacher = rost.Teacher
LEFT JOIN YRTR tr
       ON tr.Teacher  = rost.Teacher
LEFT JOIN students b
      on b.Teacher    = rost.Teacher
     AND b.regdate >= @Startdate
     AND b.regdate <  DATEADD(DAY,1,@Enddate)
LEFT JOIN dbo.potstudents c
      ON c.Teacher    = rost.Teacher
     AND c.returndate >= @Startdate
     AND c.returndate <  DATEADD(DAY,1,@Enddate)
GROUP BY rost.[Teacher], fc.TEAM, fc.fc 
ORDER BY rost.[Teacher] ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't immediate see anything that will improve performance, but I can see dozens of things you can do to better format your SQL so that that someone on here can give you a performance improving answer.

First of all, it is completely valid in SQL to write many words on the same line. In fact, SQL server will ignore all of the white space in parsing, so you can write as much or as little on a single line as you want. So the lines that currently read

```
WITH fc As
(
    Select
    Teacher
    ,Team
    ,fc
    FROM [Helper].[dbo].[fc]
)
```

Could be written as:

```
WITH fc as (SELECT Teacher, Team, fc
    FROM [Helper].[dbo].[fc])
```

As could all of the other common table expressions.

Further, all of the:

```
LEFT JOIN YRTR tr
ON rost.Teacher = tr.Teacher
```

Can be written as:

```
LEFT JOIN YRTR tr ON rost.Teacher = tr.Teacher
```

If you can compact the SQL making these types of adjustments the SQL becomes a lot more readable, will fit on one page, and you'll be much more likely to see how to fix the functional parts.

As for the functional parts, one red-flag that jumps out is that you are calling DISTINCT in scenarios where you are using a GROUP BY clause. Calling DISTINCT and GROUP BY in the same select is redundant, since GROUP BY will already ensure the results are distinct.

I'm not sure if removing the DISTINCTs will speed up the query, but since they are redundant it is worth a shot.

Also, the generic advice of "run your script in SSMS, turn on the actual execution plan and add any suggested missing indexes" is usually helpful in these situations, you could be missing an index, and if it is an important one you could get significant performance gains without much analysis.

Comment: Does removing the whitespace as you suggested, have any effect on query performance, or is that more of a personal preference/readability thing?

Comment: Strictly readability. If you can get a query on a single page, with no horizontal or vertical scrolling you'll find performance optimizations much more quickly, because you'll have the entirety of it in front of you. Many times I miss optimizations to SQL because I'm scrolling through thousands of lines of code and I can't see the big picture.